# Device Driver, Cannot Remove rmmod: ERROR: module is in use

Tags: module, kernel, device-driver

In attempts to remove a driver (simple_char_driver).., by running

```
sudo rmmmod simple_char_driver
```

I receive the following error.

```
rmmod: ERROR: Module simple_char_driver is in use
```

After running lsmod... it shows that its already in use by (2)

```
Module                  Size  Used by
helloModule            16384  0
simple_char_driver     16384  2
```

I would like to remove this module.

Ive looked online and no solution helps remotely!

I need help! Thank you!

Comment: Probably, you forget to implement `module_cleanup()` function (or use `module_exit()`) in your module. Without code of your module, we can only *guess*. BTW, you may also look into `dmesg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rmmod -f` to force the removal. But this is unsafe and can damage other things.
You can use it only if you are sure you module is isolated.

For more info, please read [here](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/rmmod.htm).